# whatsapp api to send message in php password creation error

Tags: php, whatsapi

```
I have downloaded whatsapp api,and i am trying to register in WART i get the ID but When i click on Request Code i get the error saying "could not request code using either sms or voice".reason:old_version.Anyone have any idea what to do? i have already checked this links below.
http://www.wahelper.com/register-whatsapp-account-tool.html 
https://github.com/mgp25/WART 
https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/WhatsApp-Registration-Flow
```

Please any one tell me another solution to create password for api

Comment: Whatsapp doesn't have an official API. It got reversed engineered and the majority got shut down for legal reasons. That api was last updated 3 years ago so I'm willing to be it's no longer working..

Comment: Chat-API was given End of Support notice in 2016...

Comment: some sites have this facilities they send their booking message in whatsapp how its work

Comment: They would have reversed it themselves. I doubt anyone here will provide that information here for you tho..